# How to add a element to a webpage that keeps refreshing with a updated price

Tags: php, ajax

```
$url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/USD.json";
$price = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo "$".$btcPrice=number_format($price['bpi']['USD']['rate_float'],2);
```

The above code when I add it to my page it shows me the current price. I am wondering what is the correct way to add code to a site that will update the price every minute without refreshing the entire page.

I just need a pointer to what method to use or even what search term to use to find information about this. I tries searches for words like price stream, live update element, timer, etc but nothing that gave me the answer to how to implement this.

Comment: You need to combination of [setInterval(function, milliseconds)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) and `ajax call`

Answer (score -1):

***"correct way to add code to a site that will update the price every minute without refreshing the entire page."***: *You shouldn't use PHP in the first place then, [send a call to the API with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) and update the data of an element!*

Edit: PHP is still good to generate it in code, but it won't support real-time connection for you to update it without refresh.